# Automatically fetch dependencies in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a list of dependencies that I need to fetch automatically in android studio, the problem is that some dependencies have theyr own dependencies.

Dependencies are:

```
"org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpclient" % "4.2.1",
"org.restlet.jse" % "org.restlet.ext.jackson" % "2.1.2",
"org.restlet.jse" % "org.restlet.ext.httpclient" % "2.1.2"
```

Is there a way to solve this problem ?
I have tryed to import the projects as libraries in eclipse but as I sayd they have theyr own libraryes so I can't do that.

Edit:

Adding them like this I get the following error:

```
compile 'org.apache.httpclient:4.2.1'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:4.2.1'
compile 'org.restlet.jse:2.1.2'
compile 'org.restlet.ext.jackson:2.1.2'
compile 'org.restlet.ext.httpclient:2.1.2'
```

Error:

```
Error:Failed to resolve: org.apache.httpclient:4.2.1:
<a href="openFile">Open File</a>
Error:Failed to resolve: org.restlet.ext.httpclient:2.1.2:
<a href="openFile">Open File</a>
Error:Failed to resolve: org.restlet.ext.jackson:2.1.2:
<a href="openFile">Open File</a>
Error:Failed to resolve: org.restlet.jse:2.1.2:
<a href="openFile">Open File</a>
```

Thanks to @Jared Burrows for helping me with the problem, I was writing the dependencies wrong, the correct way to do it is:

```
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.2.1'
compile 'org.restlet.jse:org.restlet.ext.jackson:2.1.2'
compile 'org.restlet.jse:org.restlet.ext.httpclient:2.1.2'
```

Comment: Can't you use Maven in Android Studio ?

Comment: Android Studio is built from Intellij which uses Gradle.

Comment: @Pavel Marian, post your entire `build.gradle`.

Comment: I am glad you got it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
"org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpclient" % "4.2.1",
"org.restlet.jse" % "org.restlet.ext.jackson" % "2.1.2",
"org.restlet.jse" % "org.restlet.ext.httpclient" % "2.1.2
```

To:

```
dependencies {
   compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.2.1'
   compile 'org.restlet.jse:org.restlet.ext.jackson:2.1.2'
   compile 'org.restlet.jse:org.restlet.ext.httpclient:2.1.2'
}
```

Adjust the versions to the latest or the ones you need.